# Shape not aligned error in OLS Regression python

Tags: python, numpy, regression, statsmodels

I have a `dataframe` where I am trying to run the `statsmodel.api` OLS regression.
It is printing out the summary. But when I am using the `predict()` function, it is giving me an error -

> shapes (75,7) and (6,) not aligned: 7 (dim 1) != 6 (dim 0)

My code is:

```
X = newdf.loc[:, newdf.columns != 'V-9'].values
y = newdf.iloc[:,3].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 
0.2,random_state=0)
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
model = sm.OLS(y_train,X_train[:,[0,1,2,3,4,6]])
result = model.fit()
print(result.summary())`
```

Error comes on running this:

```
y_pred = result.predict(X_test)
```

Shape of my `X_train` is - `(297,7)`
Shape of my `X_test` is - `(75,7)`
`dtype` is `numpy.ndarray`

This question has been asked before. I have followed some posts on stackoverflow.com and tried to solve it using `reshape` function. However, it didnt help me. Can anyone explain why I am getting this error? and what is the solution?

Comment: did you deliberately missed 5 in [0,1,2,3,4,6]? Because that makes your input to your regression 6 dimensional, while the X_test you pass had 7 and thus `7(dim1)!+6(dim0)`

Comment: Yes I dropped the 5th variable because its p-value was more than 0.05. I want the model to have 6 variables. But my X-test should have all 7 variables. How do I achieve that?

Comment: then try `y_pred = result.predict(X_test[:,[0,1,2,3,4,6]])`

Comment: Thanks @D_Serg..that solved my issue!! Please write it as an answer, so I can mark it as 'accepted solution' and close the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`model` in line `model = sm.OLS(y_train,X_train[:,[0,1,2,3,4,6]])`, when trained that way, assumes the input data is 6-dimensional, as the 5th column of `X_train` is dropped. This requires the test data (in this case `X_test`) to be 6-dimensional too. This is why `y_pred = result.predict(X_test)` didn't work because `X_test` is originally 7-dimensional. The proper fix here is:

`y_pred = result.predict(X_test[:, [0,1,2,3,4,6]]`

## BONUS

I see you are using the Pandas library. A better practice to drop columns is to use `.drop` so instead of

`newdf.loc[:, newdf.columns != 'V-9'].values`

you can use

`newdf.drop('V-9', axis=1) # axis=1 makes sure cols are dropped, not rows`

likewise instead of

`X_train[:,[0,1,2,3,4,6]]`

you can use

`X_train.drop(X_train.columns[5], axis=1) # this like dropping the 5th column of the dataFrame`

This makes it more readable and easier to code especially if you had 50 dimensions instead of 7.

I am glad it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error occurred because my original logistic regression had a constant (added using exog = sm.add_constant(exog)), but my test dataset didn't have this same constant. This caused a shape mismatch similar to the one that you had. I resolved the issue by adding a value of 1 to every row in my test DataFrame. (If this method is incorrect, or if there's a more elegant solution, please let me know.)